# Microsoft SQL Server 2005 check if temporary table empty

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

Is there a fast/efficiency way to check if a table is empty?

```
DECLARE @StartEndTimes TABLE
(
    id bigint,
    StartTime datetime,
    EndTime datetime
)

IF @StartEndTimes IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Just an FYI The code above creates a table variable not a temp table. Temp tables are preceded with # and stored in the tempdb and will I believe continue to exist until the instance of sql is restarted and the tempdb is recreated.

Comment: Actually, they may be pretty much the same (but in a different scope), according to some research done by SQL pros: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/12/15/sql-server-difference-temptable-and-table-variable-temptable-in-memory-a-myth/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than counting you can;

```
if exists (select id from @StartEndTimes)
   set @has_stuff = 1
```

Which will return as soon as it hits a row.

Comment: +1 so would I. it looks for a row and returns...count has to traverse the table

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet might be [COUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)

```
DECLARE @StartEndTimes TABLE 
( 
    id bigint, 
    StartTime datetime, 
    EndTime datetime 
)

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @StartEndTimes
```